# How to set zoom in an Excel spreadsheet embedded on a Word document to 100%?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have an embedded Excel spreadsheet in my Word document.
It is stretched.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2007 (and perhaps later versions as well), you can change the displayed size and aspect ratio of an embedded spreadsheet. Simply right-click on the embedded spreadsheet, select Format Object, and change the Height and Width on the Size tab to match the Height and Width in the Original Size section of the tab. (The easiest way to do this is to set Height and Width to 100% in the Scale section.)

Comment: The Format Object doesn't appear when right clicking on the object in Visio 2016.  Very annoying - now when I edit an embedded Excel table in a Visio doc, as soon as I move the focus elsewhere, it jumps to 150% zoom, so I can't see the whole table.  Extremely frustrating.